# What does ‘non-parter’ mean?

Tags: nouns, meaning-in-context

> In the sleuth hound of 6, Wilbraham Place, Sloane Square, however, he speedily discovered that he had come up against one of the Untouchables, a man to whom even Oofy Prosser, that outstanding non-parter, would have felt compelled to raise his hat.

What does this word *non-parter* mean in this bit of *Uncle Fred in the Springtime* by P.G. Wodehouse?

Comment: *Non-parter* is a non-word. *Parter* is itself a made-up word, "A broadcast or published work with a specified number of parts: *the first in a six-parter*" (The Free Dictionary).

Comment: @Kris: If you think PG Wodehouse has less right (and less skill) to coin words than the Free Dictionary you must be blotto.

Comment: @TimLymington  In the seventies, Sir Pelham never said anything to me about it. So maybe not. His was 'light writing' and his characters' appropriately slang or Shakespearean.

Answer (score 6):

A man who is unwilling to part with money (difficult to borrow from or 'touch', hence the pun on *Untouchable*).